# RxJS - Where did the Rx.Observable.prototype.toMap operator go?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working on an Angular 2 project and I'm trying to create a RxJS Observable 'entitiesById' hash/map. In the RxJS Github repo [there's mentioning of the `.toMap()` operator](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/tomap.md). But in my npm installed `rxjs` package, it can't be found. Only `toArray()` and `.toPromise()` are available.

It was probably removed, because the `.toMap()` transformation should be coded differently or a better alternative should be used.

What's the RxJS (or Angular 2) best practice to get the same result (i.e. a map/hash of objects by some key)?

Comment: `toMap` is gone https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer. So that confirms my assumption. Any idea on an alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `reduce` should work for this

```ts
someObservable
.reduce(function(oldVal, newVal) {
  oldVal[newVal.name] = newVal;
  return oldVal;
}, {});
```

where `newVal.name` takes the `name` property of the value and uses it as key for the map and assigns the whole new value as value (adapt to your needs)

Comment: Thanks Günter. The code needed a small syntax change (I applied it to your answer, but it's currently being peer reviewed to show up), but the .reduce suggestion works great!